# How to make a string to point to a variable in Less?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, less

I extended default less functions to support some basic lists. I added a function 'nth' given as following:

```
"nth": function(obj, index){
    var list = obj.value.split(",");
    var n = index.value;
    obj.value = list[n-1].trim();
    return new tree.Anonymous(obj);
 }
```

Then I added another function 'convertstrtovar' as following:

```
convertstrtovar: function(obj){
     var str = obj.value.toString();
     str = str.replace(/(@)/gi, '');
     str = '~"@{' + str + '}"';
     obj.value = str;
     return new tree.Anonymous(obj);
}
```

This receives String like '@white' and converts it to ~"@{white}". Sample code for less mixin is given below.

```
@button-text-colors: "@white, @dark, @red"; //parsed as a comma separated list.
@white: white;
@dark: black;
@red: red;

.something(@color){
    color: @color;
}

.some{
    @t: convertstrtovar(nth(@button-text-colors, 1));
    .something(@t);
}
```

This gives me output as following:

```
.some {
    color: ~"@{white}";
}
```

Why is ~"@{white}" being printed out as string and not evaluated as variable white when usually ~"@{white}" in less get the value stored in @white?

Comment: Sounds like you need a second iteration of evaluation? No idea if this will help, but maybe take a look: http://movableapp.com/2012/08/execute-complex-javascript-in-lesscss/.

Comment: @user2036771
> "nth": function(obj, index);
Doh! you're reinventing a wheel again: LESS already has extract function which does exactly the same

Comment: @seven-phases-max I can't find any reference to extract(). Can you please point me to it?

Comment: I found it. I didn't check the beta releases page. So how can I use a string to point to a variable same name. Is there any way to access all the declared variables, something like global.variables?

Comment: https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Built-In-Functions. But at least you could look through list of the functions in the file you edit (i.e. `functions.js`). `Extract` is just a few lines below the point you put your own functions at :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is ~"@{white}" being printed out as string and not evaluated as variable white when usually ~"@{white}"

Because LESS evaluates those things when it parses the input (but your function creates a new string object after that).

Actually you can achieve what you want just with default LESS language constructs (w/o any need for custom function hacks):

```
@button-text-colors: 'white', 'dark', 'red';
@white: white;
@dark: black;
@red: red;

.something(@color){
    color: @color;
}

.some{
    @t: extract(@button-text-colors, 1);
    .something(@@t);
}
```

No, seriously, I would suggest you to consider to learn more about existing LESS features before trying to extend it with you own custom functions... (Though I must admit the outdated LESS documentation is a significant problem - well, at least take a look at https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/_pages - this is the most detailed LESS documentation for the moment).

Comment: I got it! Thanks for helping. I should have searched more :). One reason for writing these custom functions is that, I am working on a project which requires me to convert SASS files to Less. So in order to keep existing things in place and to reduce the number of changes, I decided to mimic the function names as they are named in SASS.

Comment: Then I also would suggest you to also take a closer look to https://github.com/less/less.js/issues - it's not that it's very to find anything particular there, but when you want to be informed of the latest features and news it's just... Btw, version 1.5.0 is in its final beta and it's also has a few minor goodies here and there that might help you in you work. (There're still a few minor issues mostly related to `sourcemaps` and advanced `extend` stuff, but in context of backward compatibility it is pretty much stable so I guess I may recommend te new version already now)

Comment: I just pulled the latest code. Working with lists and newer functions is simply awesome. Thanks.